# module 'psutil' has no attribute 'process_iter' in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, psutil

I am using python 3.5.2 on windows10 machine and having problems running a py script.
I am getting this error: 'psutil has no attribute process_iter' if either use psutil.process_iter() or psutil.process.get_list().

I have psutil 5.4.3 installed.

Downloaded and tried this file https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil.. no luck

Here is the code:

```
import psutil
def processcheck(seekitem):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    #for proc in psutil.get_process_list():
        if proc.name() == seekitem:
```

....

```
for process in machine_process:
    processcheck(process)
```

Any idea how can you get around this?
It works in Linux though.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when my script was named psutil.py
Just rename your file if you have the same issue.